# Dataframe manipulation and aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
    City       Status     q1  q2 Record
0   Austin     Standard   N   Y  Active
1   Dallas     Standard   N   y  Active
2   Orlando    Standard   N   N  Active 
3   Orlando    Ex         Y   Y  Inactive
4   Orlando    Standard   N   N  Active
```

I'm trying to manipulate it to look like this:

```
                Count  %
All Cities      5      100.0%
Active          4      80%
  Ex            1      20%
  Standard      4      80%
  Q1 = Y        1      20%
  Q2 = Y        2      40%
Inactive        1      20%
```

I have resorted to a large piece of code that calculates each percent by breaking each df column into its component statuses (for example, a column for q1yes, a column for q1no, etc) and then fills a dataframe recursively but I feel like I must be missing something.

I will also need to break it down by city but I'd like to figure that part out before asking for more help

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
In [159]: df.q1 = 'Q1 = ' + df.q1.str.upper()

In [160]: df.q2 = 'Q2 = ' + df.q2.str.upper()

In [161]: df
Out[161]:
      City    Status      q1      q2    Record
0   Austin  Standard  Q1 = N  Q2 = Y    Active
1   Dallas  Standard  Q1 = N  Q2 = Y    Active
2  Orlando  Standard  Q1 = N  Q2 = N    Active
3  Orlando        Ex  Q1 = Y  Q2 = Y  Inactive
4  Orlando  Standard  Q1 = N  Q2 = N    Active

In [173]: r = (df.drop('City',1)
   .....:        .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
   .....:        .apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
   .....:        .to_frame('Count')
   .....:        .astype(np.int16)
   .....:     )

In [174]: r['pct'] = (r.Count / len(df) * 100).astype(str) + '%'

In [175]: r.loc['All Cities'] = [len(df), '100.0%']

In [176]: r
Out[176]:
            Count     pct
Active          4   80.0%
Ex              1   20.0%
Inactive        1   20.0%
Q1 = N          4   80.0%
Q1 = Y          1   20.0%
Q2 = N          2   40.0%
Q2 = Y          3   60.0%
Standard        4   80.0%
All Cities      5  100.0%
```

and finally:

```
In [178]: r[~r.index.str.contains('= N')]
Out[178]:
            Count     pct
Active          4   80.0%
Ex              1   20.0%
Inactive        1   20.0%
Q1 = Y          1   20.0%
Q2 = Y          3   60.0%
Standard        4   80.0%
All Cities      5  100.0%
```